# How do I get all nodes from neo4J REST

Tags: neo4j

Is it possible to get all nodes from the REST APIs? There are posts about Cypher but not REST.

I tried doing /node and /nodes but neither seemed to work.

Answer (score 0):

No need for a rest endpoint, Cypher is all you need.

```
:POST /db/data/transaction/commit {"statements":[{"statement":"MATCH (n) RETURN n"}]}
```

With an additional parameter `,"resultDataContents":["row","graph","REST"]` per statement you can select the result format.